# Prevent overwrite pop-up when writing into excel using a powershell

Tags: windows, excel, csv, powershell, dialog

I have a bunch of csv files from which I am writing data into a particular worksheet of an existing excel file. I have the below code and it works while looping through the CSV files and writing data into the existing worksheet

$CSVs ="rpt.test1",
"rpt.test2"

foreach ($csv in $CSVs)
{
    $csv_name = $csv
    echo "`n - - - $sav_name - - -`n"

```
foreach ($source in $Sources)
{
    $src = $source

    $inputCSV = "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\$src.$csv_name.csv"
    $Path = "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\$csv_name.xlsx"

    ### Create a new Excel Workbook with one empty sheet
    #$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
    #$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
    #$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)


    # Open the Excel document and pull in the 'Play' worksheet
    $excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($Path) 
    $page = 'data'
    $worksheet = $Workbook.worksheets | where-object {$_.Name -eq $page}

    # Delete the current contents of the page
    $worksheet.Cells.Clear() | Out-Null

    ### Build the QueryTables.Add command
    ### QueryTables does the same as when clicking "Data » From Text" in Excel
    $TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $inputCSV)
    $Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
    $query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)

    ### Set the delimiter (, or ;) according to your regional settings
    $query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $Excel.Application.International(5)

    ### Set the format to delimited and text for every column

    $query.TextFileParseType  = 1
    $query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,2 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
    $query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1

    ### Execute & delete the import query
    $query.Refresh()
    $query.Delete()

    $Workbook.SaveAs($Path,51)
    $excel.Quit()
}
```

Since it is an existing excel workbook, it throws a pop-up every time a file is being over-written. Have more than 15 CSV's and clicking Yes everytime is annoying

I have tried

```
$excel.DisplayAlerts = FALSE
```

and I have tried

```
$excel.CheckCompatibility = $False
```

and pretty much anything available on the internet. I am still learning powershell and at my wits end trying to stop this. Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: If you can't prevent the "overwrite?" popup then can you not delete the file before you perform the SaveAs ? If (Test-Path $Path){Remove-Item $Path} (grabbing random answer from Google there...)

Comment: I cannot delete and recreate the file since worksheet 1 has formulas and I am writing only into worksheet 1. That is the biggest problem that I've been facing.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding your problem - assumed you were getting an error on the second to last "SaveAs" line.  If there is a file there and you're going to overwrite it, why can't you delete it ?  Why are you using `SaveAs` instead of `Save` (since you're saving the file to the same path and name where it was opened from) ?

Comment: @TimWilliams - That was the first thing I tried, The script doesnt seem to recognize Save and threw an error.

Comment: I found a workaround this. I saved the templates in one folder, copied data into them and saved them in a different folder.

Instead of doing this, 
     `$Workbook.SaveAs($Path,51)`

I did this and it worked.
  `$Workbook.SaveAs($OutPath,51)`

Comment: Save doesn't take any parameters: what was the error ?

Answer (score 14):

Use display alerts statement before the `SaveAs` call:

```
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false;
$excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs($xlsFile);
```

Comment: I just found out that it's crucial that `$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false` happens just before the `SaveAs` call without any other actions in between. If you simply set it somewhere at the beginning of your script (e.g. just after creating the `$excel` instance) it gets reset for some reason when you do other worksheet/book actions.

Answer (score 4):

`$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false` worked for me.

Comment: Please explain how/why it worked for the given problem?

Answer (score 1):

do an if statement to check if the file exists, delete it, save the new one as that file.

```
If(Test-Path $filepath)
{
    Remove-Item $filepath -verbose
 }
$workbook.SaveAS($filepath)
```